# How many output pins do NodeMCU have?

Tags: nodemcu

I am trying to build a Smarthome system with NodeMCU.
NodeMCU would wire up with relays.
How many replays can one NodeMCU control?

Comment: It depends how many shift registers or IO expanders you are willing to use.

Comment: Juraj I know, but I don't know the get those GPIOs things.
Can you give me a short answer?